# Клавиша ПКМ на клавиатуре в KDE

Tags: linux, kde, kubuntu

У меня ноутбук с Kubuntu 19.04 (KDE 5), и на его клавиатуре нет клавиши, которая выполненяет нажатие ПКМ (обычно она с изображением страницы), что сильно мешает работе без мышки. Как можно назначить нажатие этой клавиши на сочетание других клавиш (например, ctrl+.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать срабатывание нажатия ПКМ на клавишу Caps Lock встроенными средствами. Для этого:

> System Settings - Hardware - Input Devices - Keyboard - Advanced

В меню *Caps Lock behavior* сделать активным пункт *Make Caps Lock an additional Menu key*. После нажать apply